# ASP.NET WebApi User.Identity returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

So, I've been trying to implement the feature of signing in with Facebook in a ASP.NET WebApi 2 application.

But for some reason, when I try to validate anonymous requests:

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
}
```

`User` is null.

I already set the authentication mode to `None` on my `web.config`.

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="None" />
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Also, this is how I configure the pipeline for OAuth in my Startup.cs class:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

    facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions() {
         AppId = "xxxxx",
         AppSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
         Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
    };
    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthOptions);
}
```

And this is how I got my controller:

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null) {
    string redirectUri = string.Empty;

    // HERE: User is always null.
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
    }

    // Rest of the code removed for brevity...
}
```

And this is how I have set up my development server:
[image]

As far as I know, `User.Identity` should contain the data/claims returned by the login provider in a cookie, but User returns null; therefore, the challenge isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ClaimsPrinicpal for the user and use "AuthorizeToken" in controller.
This is basically set when you have got Token. Complete mechanism is governed by Owin Pipeline.

You need to get Owin context and unprotect the token and assign it to "AuthenticationTicket". (AuthenticationTicket is class in "Microsoft.Owin.Security")

```
public class AuthorizeTokenAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
      public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
          SetUserContext(actionContext.Request.GetOwinContext()
       }

    private bool SetUserIdentity(IOwinContext context)
    {
        AuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = 
        Startup.OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);

        context.Authentication.User = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal();                      
        context.Authentication.User.AddIdentity(authenticationTicket.Identity);


    }
}
```

After assigning value to "User" in above way, you won't get User as null and will be able to fetch Identity as well after assigning it.

Comment: @rottencheese Please accept the answer if you find it useful